# Emberjs container view, How can I select a child view by name from a container. When the child view is added programmatically

Tags: ember.js

How can I select a child view by name from a container. When the child view is added programmatically.

```
aContainer = Ember.ContainerView.create({

  });

AnotherViewClass = Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("Another view")
  });

aContainer.get('childViews').pushObject(AnotherViewClass.create());
var selectedView = aContainer.get('bView');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the child view name to container after adding it, just like this:

```
var bView = AnotherViewClass.create();

aContainer.get('childViews').pushObject(bView);
aContainer.set('bView', bView);
```

After this step, you can get it by name:

```
var selectedView = aContainer.get('bView');
```

See this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/tualatrix/FEvSc/1/, the console will output the right child view.